# Read range of values in an array with unkown dimension

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I 'm looking for a way to read a range of elements in an array of unknown dimension ( not length).

The client can send a read request for an object and specify the range to read. The input String could be like this : "1:2:3:2,2:3:1:4" for example. This would mean he wants to read the elements in the range from [1][2][3][2]  to [2][3][1][4] of an array.

To read a concrete element I created this function:

```
public Object readValue(Object obj,int[] positions ) {
    Object value = null;    //Result
    int objDimension = getDimension(obj); //Dimesion of the array
    System.out.println("Dimension: " + objDimension );
    try {
        Object[] aux = (Object[]) obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < objDimension - 1; i++) {
            int pos = positions[i];
            aux = (Object[]) aux[pos];
        }
        value = aux[positions[objDimension - 1]];
        System.out.println("Result: " + value);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        // TODO: Send a fault to the client.
        System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return value;
}

public static int getDimension(Object value) {
    Class<?> clazz = value.getClass();
    String className = clazz.getName();
    int dimension = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < className.length(); i++) {
        if (className.charAt(i) != '[') {
            dimension = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return dimension;
}


//Example.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    TestMultiDimensioNRead test = new TestMultiDimensioNRead();
    Integer[][][][] testSubject = new Integer[5][2][4][];

    testSubject[0][0][2] = new Integer[8];
    testSubject[0][0][0] = new Integer[15];
    testSubject[0][0][1] = new Integer[20];
    testSubject[0][0][3] = new Integer[2];
    testSubject[1][1][2] = new Integer[7];
    testSubject[1][1][2][0] = 80;
    test.readValue(testSubject,new int[]{1, 1, 2, 0});
}
```

I was thinking a good way may be to calculate the differens between each dimension length.

If anyone can come with a good idea, I would really appreciatee.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: The code posted in this question does read the value of a given position in an array of unknown dimension. My problem is to read all the elements that are between to given points. This might not have been clear in the initial question.

Comment: This is probably not a suggested approach for many reasons.  Can I ask what you're trying to accomplish overall?  I'd probably rethink the way you're going at the problem.

Comment: It´s for a server, one of the services is to read a range of values from an array of any dimesion. The arrays are not predefined, and have no dimesion limit ( i wrote 255, because of the dimension cap from Java). This are created when the server start, and come from configuration files. By the way any alternative way or idea is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Could you pass the dimensions in with the data as parameters? No sense in writing an algorithm to figure it out if the calling code knows it (for this usage at least).

Comment: Yes, that is not a problem, and no need to worry about checking for exception. I am really looking for a way to read a range. The other details are not really important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to do it, maybe it's helpfull at somepoint for someone.
I didn't include any checks, this is more a test case to see that is works.

```
public class TestReadMultiDimensionArray {

private int[] startPosition;                //Start position.
private int[] endPosition;                  //End position.
private boolean inRange = false;            //If the current position is in range.
private List<Object> result;                //List to store the values we find.

public TestReadMultiDimensionArray() {
    result = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestReadMultiDimensionArray test = new TestReadMultiDimensionArray();
    Integer[][][][] testSubject = new Integer[2][2][4][];
    //(0,0,y,z)
    testSubject[0][0][0] = new Integer[]{1};                                    //(0,0,0,0)
    testSubject[0][0][1] = new Integer[]{2};                                    //(0,0,1,0)
    testSubject[0][0][2] = new Integer[]{3};                                    //(0,0,2,0)
    testSubject[0][0][3] = new Integer[]{4};                                    //(0,0,3,0)
    //(0,1,y,z)
    testSubject[0][1][0] = new Integer[]{5};                                    //(0,1,0,0)
    testSubject[0][1][1] = new Integer[]{6};                                    //(0,1,1,0)
    testSubject[0][1][2] = new Integer[]{7, 8, 9};                              //(0,1,2,0) (0,1,2,1) (0,1,2,2)
    testSubject[0][1][3] = new Integer[]{10};                                   //(0,1,3,0)
    //(1,0,y,z)
    testSubject[1][0][0] = new Integer[]{11, 12};                               //(1,0,0,0)..
    testSubject[1][0][1] = new Integer[]{13, 14, 15};
    testSubject[1][0][2] = new Integer[]{16, 17, 18};
    testSubject[1][0][3] = new Integer[]{19, 20, 21};                           //..(1,0,3,2)
    //(1,1,y,z)
    testSubject[1][1][0] = new Integer[]{22, 23};                               //(1,1,0,0)..
    testSubject[1][1][1] = new Integer[]{24, 25, 26};
    testSubject[1][1][2] = new Integer[]{27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34};
    testSubject[1][1][3] = new Integer[]{35, 36};                               //..(1,1,3,1)
    //Launch the test.
    test.readValue(testSubject);
}

/**
 *
 * @param obj The Array from where we want to get the data.
 */
public void readValue(Object obj) {
    //Where should it start.
    startPosition = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 0};
    //Where should it stop.
    endPosition = new int[]{1, 1, 1, 2};
    System.out.println("Start Position:" + Arrays.toString(startPosition) + " End Position:" + Arrays.toString(endPosition));
    int[] currentPosition = new int[]{-1, -1, -1, -1};

    //Call to the method.
    testRead((Object[]) obj, 0, currentPosition);
    //Result to array.
    Object[] arrayToReturn = result.toArray(new Object[0]);
    System.out.println("Result: " + Arrays.toString(arrayToReturn));
}

/**
 * Recursive method that looks for the values in a multi-dimensional array, in a given range. /!\ No checks are implemented here, wrong input can end in a
 * StackOverFlow.
 *
 * @param obj The array in Object[] form.
 * @param currentDimension The dimension we are currently in.
 * @param result The reference to the list that will store all the values we found.
 * @param currentPosition The current position we are in.
 */
private void testRead(Object[] obj, int currentDimension, int[] currentPosition) {
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        currentPosition[currentDimension] = i;
        if (Arrays.equals(startPosition, currentPosition) && currentDimension == (currentPosition.length - 1)) {
            //Found the start position.
            System.out.println("############ START ############");
            inRange = true;
        }

        if ((i >= startPosition[currentDimension] && i <= endPosition[currentDimension]) || inRange == true) {
            //We are in the write track to get to the values we are looking for.
            if (obj[i] instanceof Object[]) {
                //The data contained in the cell is an array.
                testRead((Object[]) obj[i], currentDimension + 1, currentPosition);
            } else {
                //The data contained in the cell is a scalar. This is what we where looking for.
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(currentPosition) + " Data: " + obj[i]);
                result.add(obj[i]);
            }
        }

        if (Arrays.equals(endPosition, currentPosition) && currentDimension == (currentPosition.length - 1)) {
            //Found the end position.
            System.out.println("############ END ############");
            inRange = false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Any question or idea to better the code is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive solution:

```
public class Test {
    private class TestMultiDimensioNRead {
        public Integer readValue(Object testSubject, int[] coordinates) {
            return readValue(testSubject, coordinates, 0);
        }

        private Integer readValue(Object testSubject, int[] coordinates, int which) {
            if (testSubject instanceof Object[]) {
                Object[] subject = (Object[]) testSubject;
                if (coordinates.length > which + 1) {
                    return readValue(subject[coordinates[which]], coordinates, which + 1);
                } else {
                    return (Integer) subject[coordinates[which]];
                }
            } else {
                // Throw some sort of exception?
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public Iterator<Integer> readValues(Object testSubject, int[] coordinates, int count) {
            return readValues(testSubject, coordinates, count, 0);
        }

        private Iterator<Integer> readValues(Object testSubject, int[] coordinates, int count, int level) {
            if (testSubject instanceof Object[]) {
                Object[] subject = (Object[]) testSubject;
                if (coordinates.length > level + 1) {
                    return readValues(subject[coordinates[level]], coordinates, count, level + 1);
                } else {
                    return new Iterator<Integer>() {
                        int i = 0;
                        Integer[] intSubject = (Integer[]) subject;

                        @Override
                        public boolean hasNext() {
                            return i <= count;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Integer next() {
                            return intSubject[coordinates[level] + (i++)];
                        }
                    };
                }
            } else {
                // Throw some sort of exception?
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

    public void test() {
        TestMultiDimensioNRead test = new TestMultiDimensioNRead();
        Integer[][][][] testSubject = new Integer[5][2][4][];

        testSubject[0][0][2] = new Integer[8];
        testSubject[0][0][0] = new Integer[15];
        testSubject[0][0][1] = new Integer[20];
        testSubject[0][0][3] = new Integer[2];
        testSubject[1][1][2] = new Integer[7];
        testSubject[1][1][2][0] = 80;
        testSubject[1][1][2][1] = 79;
        testSubject[1][1][2][2] = 78;
        Iterator<Integer> them = test.readValues(testSubject, new int[]{1, 1, 2, 0}, 3);
        for (Integer x = them.next(); them.hasNext(); x = them.next()) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            new Test().test();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Prints `80` as expected.

There's probably more to do in terms of sanity checks but this seems to work.

Comment: I see what you mean, but really the problem is to read the range. I mean the range can be somehitng like: Read from the element [0][0][0][0] to [4][1][1][0]. Meaning you have to read all the elements that are in between this two. The result would be an array with all the values that are present in that range. An easy example could be: read from [0][0][0][0] to [0][0][0][5], this would be [0][0][0][0],[0][0][0][1],[0][0][0][2],[0][0][0][3],[0][0][0][4] and [0][0][0][5].

Comment: @gabun88 - You could probably do that by returning a hastily constructed `Iterator` at the level we find the correct locaton but only if the range is at the deepest level. It would be difficult to do something like `[0][0][0][0] to [0][0][5][5]` for example.

Comment: @gabun88 - I've added a `readValues` that returns an `Iterator` - hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! this looks really interesting. I will take a closer look at it this evening, really appreciate!

Comment: Sorry for the time it took to look at the code. What I'm thinking is that this is maybe a better way of not depending on the class signature, but at the end the problem with reading a range of values is still there.  The coordinates will alwais point to the last level of the array, the real problem is read everything that is in between. For example from [0][0][0][0] to [1][2][2][1]. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @gabun88 - As that is a 4-dimensional slice you need to decide what you mean by _read everything in between_. Should it look like a 4d array or do you just want the numbers etc.

Comment: I only need to read all the values (numbers) of that n-dimensional slice. I'm sorry, really trying my best to explain it.